# mysql error #1064 while creating table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Exhibitor_Info
(Ex_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,User_id int,Category varchar(150),Description varchar(400), PRIMARY KEY(Ex_id),FOREIGN KEY(User_id));
```

while executing this sql I got the following error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2**

Can anyone help me to fix the problem

thanks

Comment: a foreign key has to reference something..

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to foreign key by replacing

```
FOREIGN KEY(User_id)
```

with

```
foreign key(user_id) references referred_table(referred_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the reference to a foreign key

CREATE TABLE Exhibitor_Info
(Ex_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,User_id int,Category varchar(150),Description varchar(400), PRIMARY KEY(Ex_id),FOREIGN KEY(User_id) 
REFERENCES referred_parent_table(referred_col) ON DELETE CASCADE);

You can have a good example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: You can also set the *ON DELETE* and *ON UPDATE* as per your requirement.

Comment: If my answer as helped you in any ways then you can **accept** my answer